# How does Eclipse actually run Junit tests?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am running into a discrepancy when running Junit tests in Eclipse and Ant. Here is the scenario:

Everything ran as intended in Eclipse, however, I could not get an accurate Junit report when running through an Ant build script I whipped up. I made a couple of changes to our test runner and test cases (in a nutshell I added the Test suite() method to all of my test cases) which returns a new Junit4TestAdapter, and had our custom runner execute RunNotifier.fireTestAssumptionFailed(Failure) instead of fireTestAssumption. Now everything runs fine in Ant, but failures are marked as passed when run in Eclipse.

Is there any documentation for Eclipse that explains exactly how it runs Junit tests? I am basically looking to know exactly how Eclipse executes Junit tests, whether it's run directly through Ant, if it uses Java to interface with Junit, etc. If anyone knows an actual solution to the issue, I welcome that as well, but I would really like to try solving this one on my own, I just need a point in the right direction.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use your ant build file to run JUnit tests. That's for sure.

Comment: I'm well aware of this, I'm trying to figure out what the discrepancy is between running the same suite of tests from Ant is than running them via the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: You might get some hints from your Eclipse Junit test launcher, especially the arguments tab and the configuration tab.

Comment: I've looked at the Run configuration window, and nothing seems to reveal a solution to me. Essentially, I know where the problem lies, the Junit plugin clearly isn't handling the testAssumptionFailure event, and I can't figure out why. Both Ant and Junit should be running the tests in the same fasion, unless something like the Eclipse plugin doesn't honor the Test suite() method, which is the type of issue I am trying to track down.

Comment: Is there any documentation for Junit command line parameters? I can't seem to find docs relating to this.

Comment: If you need the command that was used by Eclipse to run the JUnit test then, go to debug perspective when your test is running and right click on the java process of the JUnit test and check the properties which will show the command.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To answer your problem first, if you have a discrepancy between the Ant junit and Eclipse JUnit, it's probably a classpath or environmental problem. The easiest way is to find a test that performs differently between the two and print out the System properties, and work at it from that direction. Another thing to try would be to run the ant scripts from within Eclipse, to see if this makes any difference (because the environment will change)

Eclipse does not use Ant to run the tests.

---

As for how Eclipse runs JUnit tests, here is a quick overview. Be warned: there is some deep magic in the Eclipse JUnit plugin.

Eclipse has 4 JUnit plugins, which are all installed by default in most configurations:

1. org.eclipse.jdt.junit: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.git
2. org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core.git
3. org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime.git
4. org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime.git

These are git mirrors of the actual CVS repositories. Last time I tried to use them, they didn't compile, but they'll give you the code and you can at least import the projects into Eclipse and look at them.

If we ignore the configuration pages, how the plugin creates run configurations, the code for the JUnit view itself and how it finds the relevant tests to run, we can concentrate on how it runs the tests.

The core classes are `org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate` and `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner`. `JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate` reads the launch configuration and forks a JVM in which the tests will be run. The main class for this new JVM is `RemoteTestRunner`. The tests to be run are passed as parameters to the forked JVM, either as a single test or as a list of tests in a temporary file if you're doing Run as JUnit on a project. If you're debugging, this new JVM can be kept alive by checking the `Keep alive when debugging` checkbox in the run configuration. In this case, the JVM will stick around and reruns of existing tests will be sent via sockets.

`RemoteTestRunner` runs the tests and passes back the results via sockets to Eclipse, which then updates the JUnit view. The heart of this is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference`, which runs the test (for JUnit 4), and `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestListener`, which is the `RunListener` for these tests. JUnit4TestListener extends `RunListener`, but doesn't override `testAssumptionFailure`, which is probably why your tests are passing in Eclipse. `RunListener.testAssumptionFailure` is an empty method, it does nothing, so your notifications will be ignored.

I would start by cloning the git repos, importing the projects into Eclipse and trying to work through the code.

Answer (score 2):

Download the **plugin development tools (PDT)** for Eclipse.

Start a plugin project and add **org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner** and **org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core** to your plugin.xml's dependancies.

Explore those classes and you will get an idea of how JUnit is launched.  It does not use Ant at all.

To see how failures are marked and manipulate the reporting you should look at **org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runtime** assumming you are using JUnit 4.

In sum, be prepared to spend a while learning and developing a plugin if you want to change how Eclipse's JUnit works.