# Call JUnit from other Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, junit

I am developing for Eclipse, and one feature is run JUnit tests. Now my plugin detect JUnit tests on a project in workspace and after this I want to call JUnit to run this tests.

I heard about ILaunch, ILaunchConfigurationDelegate, JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate but I cannot found an example of this and also I'm not sure if I have to use this!

-- Thanks in advance

Comment: Please accept and vote up some answers, otherwise people won't answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my answer to [How does Eclipse actually run Junit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892070/how-does-eclipse-actually-run-junit-tests/7896628#7896628). You will need to create a Run Configuration and then call JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate#launch() with the configuration.

The easiest way to do this is to add shortcuts to the extension point `org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts`. With the correct configurationType, you can create the correct type and normally, Eclipse will do the rest. In fact this is exactly what we've done in the [Scala IDE](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide).

Here is the relevant XML from scala-ide:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts">
    <shortcut
          label="%JUnitShortcut.label"
          icon="$nl$/icons/full/obj16/julaunch.gif"
          helpContextId="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launch_shortcut"
          class="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchShortcut"
          modes="run, debug"
          id="scala.tools.eclipse.scalatest.junitShortcut">
       <contextualLaunch>
          <enablement>
             <with variable="selection">
                <count value="1"/>
                <iterate>
                   <adapt type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaElement">
                      <test property="org.eclipse.debug.ui.matchesPattern" value="*.scala"/>
                      <test property="org.eclipse.jdt.core.isInJavaProject"/>
                      <test property="org.eclipse.jdt.core.hasTypeOnClasspath" value="junit.framework.Test"/>
                      <or>
                      <test property="scala.tools.eclipse.launching.canLaunchAsJUnit" forcePluginActivation="true"/>
                      <test property="scala.tools.eclipse.launching.junit.canLaunchAsJUnit" forcePluginActivation="true"/>
                      </or>
                   </adapt>
                </iterate>
             </with>
          </enablement>
       </contextualLaunch>
       <configurationType
             id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launchconfig">
       </configurationType>
       <description
             description="%DebugJUnitLaunchShortcut.description"
             mode="debug">
       </description>
       <description
             description="%RunJUnitLaunchShortcut.description"
             mode="run">
       </description>
    </shortcut>
</extension>
```

The important element is the <contextualLaunch>, which defines a set of tests which need to be true in order that the option to launch as JUnit be presented to the user. Most of these are self explanatory, but we've also `scala.tools.eclipse.launching.canLaunchAsJUnit`, which references an extension point `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters`. These property testers test whether the code can be launched as JUnit or not (for instance, the class under test extends TestCase or whatever).

If you need more details, I recommend downloading [Scala IDE](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide), and looking at the code, but it is written in Scala.

Comment: Matthew, thank for your help.
So, 1. I need a _Run Configuration_, how can I create a _Run Configuration_? _Run Configuration_ is a ILaunchConfiguration?
2., as you said in other thread "JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate reads the launch configuration and forks a JVM in which the tests will be run. The tests to be run are passed as parameters to the forked JVM" how can I pass the tests to the JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate?
The launch method is launch(ILaunchConfiguration configuration, String mode, ILaunch ilaunch, IProgressMonitor monitor) but I cannot understand what is this paremeters...

Comment: Like I said, te easiest way is to extend the shortcuts like in the XML above with the combination of the class=org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchShortcut and configurationType, this should create the configuration automatically for you and run, because you're extending the JUnitLaunchShortcut

Comment: Matthew, thank for your help. I do some experiments and extending my plugin.xml I can call JUnit and it run all test in my project. But I don't wont this, I want some test to run, not all of them! Who select tests to run? My plugin look for an project and choose some tests in real time, after this it calls JUnit to run the tests selected...

Comment: With this [CallJUnitView](http://pastie.org/2842506) I can call JUnit View with some tests, :) but it's not perfect... To use this I need a existent 'Run Configuration' in workspace, which had configured what test are to execute... How can I create a new Configuration in code, that select only the tests I want and after launch that new configuration?

Comment: After a lot of hours, I think it is impossible to do what I want... RunConfiguration of Eclipse doesn't support run for several Test Cases selected by me! Only runs a **SingleTestClass** or one **Project**, **Package** or **SourceFolder**, doesn't run multiple Test Cases from several packages. ( I'm sad :-(  )

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote part of launche junit services, then inform the project it calls the debug and run.

See my implementation to call  the [JUnitLaunch](https://github.com/samueltcsantos/priorjplugin/blob/master/src/com/edu/ufcg/splab/priorj/core/JUnitLaunch.java)