# How to integrate Junit plugin into my custom plug in?

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, junit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call JUnit from other Eclipse Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064249/call-junit-from-other-eclipse-plugin)

In my Eclipse custom plugin, I can do the unit test with junit. I want to show the results on Junit plugin's view. How to call code in Junit plugin in my custom plugin? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either create a TestSuite and fake out the tests to generate your desired output or try to reuse the console part of the junit plugin.

otherwise your only other choice is to patch the junit plugin which is not recommended because you can screw up the plugin and it is difficult to garauntee will run the same on all versions of eclipse.