# Possible to run a given JUnit test programatically from my own Eclipse Plugin? How?

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, junit4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call JUnit from other Eclipse Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064249/call-junit-from-other-eclipse-plugin)

I am trying to have a set of JUnit4 tests be run programatically from my own Eclipse plugin. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Keep in mind what I'm looking for is to have Eclipse show up the usual TestsView, just as if I had done a standard run on a test manually (otherwise, I could have just initiated a standard run with the JUnit library classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging..

```
JUnitLaunchShortcut jUnitLaunchShortcut = new JUnitLaunchShortcut();
jUnitLaunchShortcut.launch(structuredSelection, "run");
```