# Integrating JUnit in a Java Application

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Is there a way to integrate the JUnit window to a Java application?

Comment: can you expalin it more ? what do you mean?

Comment: I mean when you run JUnit under Eclipse you will have this JUnit perspective right? Can you take that perspective and integrate it to another java application so that you run the junit not on eclipse.

Comment: not the screen but maybe if you really need it, you can simulate it.        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(MyClassTest.class);
  for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
   System.out.println(failure.toString());
  } you can take failure like this and show the result.

Answer (score 2):

The JUnit view is highly integrated and dependent upon the Eclipse (not just RCP) environment, the junit plugins are quite complex and would probably not be a good place to start. It would be very difficult to integrate them into another application. Your best bet would be to write your own GUI, and integrate JUnit yourself.

If you still want to do this, then the source for the JUnit plugins is available from

1. org.eclipse.jdt.junit: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.git
2. org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core.git
3. org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime.git
4. org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime.git

For a start, see my answer to the question [How does Eclipse actually run Junit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892070/how-does-eclipse-actually-run-junit-tests/7896628#7896628)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if your using swt, then all you have to do is check the JUnit plugin source code and integrate accordingly, I'm afraid this would be a little of a mess if you're not familiar with programming in the eclipse environment. 
As an alternative, go through the JUnit api and build your interface accordingly.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking it can be achieved if I use RCP.