# Eclipse junit test discovery

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

In eclipse - the junit test runner will find this test:

```
class Blah { 
    public static class Tests {
        [Test] void testOne() {}
}}
```

but it won't find this test

```
class Blah<T> { 
    public static class Tests {
        [Test] void testOne() {}
}}
```

Can anyone explain why, and is it possible to fix that in some way?

Comment: how will eclipse figure out the value for T

Comment: it's a static subclass - to T is irrelevant... Java doesn't push the template variable through to any static elements

Comment: There seems to be a mix between C# and Java in this question....

Answer (score 2):

I can't explain why eclipse won't accept generic classes to run as JUnit test. This might be a bug, but I could not find anything on the issue tracker.

There are now two ways to work around your problem. You can manually create a run-configuration for your test and start this. The other way is to use a test suite. Add a new class to your test-package containing the following

```
package com.prodyna.packetcapture.text;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Blah.class })
public class AllTests {

}
```

You can run this normally as JUnit-test and it will run all test classes that you specify in the `SuiteClasses` annotation.

Comment: thanks - but we actually run with an external runner anyway for the full tests under CI - what I'm really looking for is the "run with junit" from the document outline... otherwise it's a good idea

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a strange one. Eclipse seems to be a bit inconsistent with this one.

First of all, we need to say that it doesn't really make sense to have a generic test like this. JUnit (and Eclipse) instantiates this class using reflection, so it doesn't care about the generic part. It probably won't work as you expect.

To explain the Eclipse part, Eclipse has two stages for executing a JUnit test: it detects whether or not the class is a JUnit test and it then executes it. It's the first part that is preventing you from running the test. If you create the generic test:

```
public class GenericTest<T> {
  @Test public void foobar() {
    System.out.println("GenericTest");
  }
}
```

Then the option 'Run as->JUnit test' isn't available on this class. If you remove the <T>, it becomes available and you can run it; it appears in the JUnit view. This is as you say.

The inconsistent part is when you put the  back, you can now re-execute the test from the JUnit view.

[image: Eclipse rerun JUnit test]

So the execution of the test actually works when the class is generic. However, you can't execute it normally in Eclipse.

For info, the JUnit view can't really prevent you from doing this, because it stores the class name in the run configuration: see [How does Eclipse actually run Junit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7896628/1836).

I don't think you'll get very far if you raise an issue, because as I said using a generic class in this way doesn't really make sense.

Comment: using a generic class in the way you mention it doesn't make sense - but using it in the way I mentioned it I do every day.   We are all about development speed/principle of least surprise - and the simplest/fastest way for us to maintain tests for class X is in a test class _inside_ X.    if X is not generic, this works perfectly.  If x is generic, it doesn't.  The test class itself is always a non-generic static class, so I can't see why eclipse would care

Comment: Like I said, it's the discovery mechanism which isn't allowing generic classes through. If you want to raise an issue, please go ahead, but be aware that the bugfix may take a while...