# Where is 'main' function invoked for JUnit test case

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I have a sample `JUnit` test case which works absolutely fine however I am not sure how did it start executing as it *does not contain main or any runner class function*. Can anyone share how is `JUnit` test case executed **without main function**?

The code is:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;

public class testJUnit {

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Before Class");
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Tear Down After Class");
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Setup");
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Tear Down");
}

@Test
public void test() {
    int a = 1;
    assertEquals("Testing...", 1, a);
}

@Ignore
@Test
public void test1() {
    int a = 156;
    assertEquals("Testing...", 156, a);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running a JUnit test from Eclipse, Eclipse runs another JVM which has it's own main class ([RemoteTestRunner](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/runner/RemoteTestRunner.java?id=d0add1708b812c80384d88ef4eb52493b862187d) if you're interested). This does effectively the same job as JUnitCore, but with changes specific for Eclipse - it needs to pass the results back to Eclipse.

For more information, see my answer to [How does Eclipse actually run Junit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7896628/1836)

Answer (score 2):

When you *run* a JUnit test, you are in fact executing `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` and providing your fully qualified class name as argument.

You are probably using an IDE, like Eclipse or Netbeans, which handle all that logic for you. See [@Matthew Farwell answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19538920/263057) on this subject.

Source : [jUnit FAQ (2006)](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_4)

Comment: Actually, when running from Eclipse, it doesn't call JUnitCore. The FAQ that you cite is from 2006.

Answer (score 0):

The class doesn't need a main method.  jUnit contains a main method for execution and at some point jUnit creates an instance of the test class.

Answer (score 0):

It is handled by the framework itself. Execution occurs in order of @Before, @Test & @After ..